# Reliability of Scimore embedded database

Tags: windows, embedded

I currently use SQLite for some applications that need a light embedded database. These apps use multiple processes that access the same database. For concurrent write access this is cumbersome. We have done some work-arounds to overcome this to some degree, but clearly SQLite has it limits.

So, we looked around and found an interesting, but very unknown, database: Scimore. It's quite capable; it's embedded version uses an out-of-process technique that allows multi-concurrency read and write access. Besides this, it's free. It's almost too good to be true.

From our first test results it seems to be very good and fast, but then why is it so unknown?

Therefore my question: Do you know this database; if so what are your experiences regarding reliability?

[Scimore website](http://www.scimore.com)

NB: I'm only asking for real usage experiences; not opinions.

Comment: I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, so please feel free to ignore. My own recommendation for you would be to use the Firebird embedded database which is multi-user safe for reads and writes and works on Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Vérace: Unfortunately, according to their own docs, the embedded database cannot handle multi-process write access, because it locks the complete database, just like SQLite does. Otherwise Firebird would indeed be a good choice.

Comment: @user45130 - are you using scimore? If so please share your findings and opinion. I am planning to use Scimore embedded in commercial application. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I've worked a few with it, and until now, it works like a charm, no concurrency problems, fast and depending on clients, lite as you want it to be.
I do not know if it would hace issues at electrical shutdowns while saving data
but i'm using it for technical data (Engineering data)

Cheers!